# How to make buttons from different form to be next to each other?

Tags: php, html, materialize

Firstly, I'm using materialize for this.I'm making two buttons, one for sign in and one for sign up, both are in different forms i made it that way so the sign up button will direct to the register page without being prevented by the required attribute, the problem is, because both buttons come from different form somehow they wont be next to each other and i don't know why is that, i need both to be next to each other (the sign up button to be next to the sign in button)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sanrio Merch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <meta  name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        body{
            background-image: url("assets/bg.gif");
            background-size: 100% 120vh;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            }
        .card{
            background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
            width: 40%;
            height: 75vh;
            margin: 9% auto;
            }
        label,input{
            color: white;
            font-size: 1em;
        }
        input{
            border-bottom: 1px solid white !important;
        }
        input:focus{
            box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 white !important;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="card">
            <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <div class="card-action white-text brown">
            <h3>SIGN IN</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <div class="form-field">
              <label for="username">Username</label>
              <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username" required="">
              <br><br>
              <label for="password">Password</label>
              <input type="password" id="password" name="pass" placeholder="password" required="">
              </div><br>
              </div><br><br>
              <div class="form-field center-align">
              <button class="btn-large brown" name ='sigin'style="margin-right: 2%;" type="submit" name="submit">Sign In</button>
              </div>
            </form>
            <form action="login.php" method="post">
            <button class="btn-large brown" name="register">Sign Up</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect the sign up button to be next to the sign in button but it doesnt display that way[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create 2 buttons without the type="submit" and add some jQuery like so:

```
$( "#button_sign_up" ).click(function() {
  $( "#form_sign_up" ).submit();
});

$( "#button_sign_in" ).click(function() {
  $( "#form_sign_in" ).submit();
});
```

This way you mark your button to perform a submit based on an form ID. Now your buttons can be anywhere on the page. Make sure you have both form and button ID's assigned